# How to register twelvemonkey.imageIO into java servicemix registery

Tags: java, apache-servicemix, twelvemonkeys

Error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException - Unsupported Image Type]
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:977)[:1.6.0_26]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:948)[:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)[:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1374)[:1.6.0_26]
    at com.brodos.test.ScaleImage.execute(ScaleImage.java:23)[914:testproject:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.brodos.test.TestProcessor.process(TestProcessor.java:57)[914:testproject:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-02-05]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-02-05]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-02-05]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-02-05]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-02-05].
```

I have already added jars to my maven project and dependencies into my `pom.xml` file as per the below comments

Comment: i have already used the library :                                           com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.0
com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-core/3.0
com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-metadata/3.0
com.twelvemonkeys.servlet/servlet/3.0
com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-batik/3.0
com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-jmagick/3.0

Comment: even installed the jars into my servicemix.
    java version : 1.6.0
    servicemix : 4.4.1-fuse-02-05
     example code : 
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://downloadurl/abc.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File ("C://test1.jpg"));                
This code works file when executing with publicstaticvoidmain. 
when we deploy into servicemix it again gives error.       
please anyone can give the solution for this issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to manually register plugins to be used with ImageIO in servicemix. But you have to  make sure that plugins are available in class path for the servicemix bundle.

```
ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soultions found was  :
First Approach :
1)  use the TwelveMonkeys library https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/

2) before making Image to be read or write as imageIo.read or imageIo.write scan for plugin using  ImageIO.scanForPlugins()  and add the twelvemonkeys lib. as maven depedency.

maven install :

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.0

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-core/3.0

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-metadata/3.0

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-batik/3.0

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-jmagick/3.0

osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:batik/batik-1.5-fop/0.20-5



<Import-Package>
    batik;resolution:=optional,
    magick;resolution:=optional,
    bsh;resolution:=optional,
    com.twelvemonkeys.*,
    *
</Import-Package>
<Export-Package>
    com.twelvemonkeys.*,
    com.google.gson.*,
    com.brodos.common.*,
</Export-Package>
<DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
<Embed-Dependency>imageio-jpeg,imageio-core,imageio-metadata,imageio.batik,imageio.jmagick;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>


Second Approach : Endorsed Mechanism
1) Add the TwelveMonkeys into servicemix /lib/endorsed directory  and the execute the application.
```